# Name of a small program dealing with symmetry groups

Tags: x11

I used to play with a small X program dealing with symmetry groups.

In a window you selected a symmetry group from a display, in another window appeared a grid of symmetry cells, drawn in thin red lines, you then draw a segment using the mouse and your segments were replicated in all the cells.

You had the possibility of saving your drawing in Postscript format.

What is/was the name of this program?

I tried to ask the big G, but I was unlucky or unable to ask the right question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be [`Kali`](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/software/download/kali.html) which was last released in 1998 bu [UMN Geometry Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_Center) but still [packaged around](https://packages.debian.org/stable/kali):

> Kali is an interactive 2D Euclidean symmetry pattern editor.

> You can use Kali to draw Escher-like tilings, infinite knots, frieze
> patterns, and other cool stuff. It lets you draw patterns in any of
> the 17 planar (wallpaper) or 7 frieze symmetry groups. Drawings are
> done interactively with X, and PostScript output is supported.

---

How did I find it? With a package search engine: I tried on Debian `apt-cache search symmetry` and among various libraries or chemical and medical results, there it was:

```
$ apt-cache search symmetry
[...]
kali - Draw tilings, frieze patterns, and so on
[...]
```

Comment: Oh, Debian! `apt*` is **very** nice, `zypper` is good but not as much...

Answer (score 0):

To complement @A.B answer, I'd like to add a few further remarks.

### Some Distributions do not package Kali

As it happens, some unnamed Linux distributions do not package `kali`, and sometimes they do not package `libforms`, the X library used to build `kali` (alas, my unnamed distribution is one of those!).

#### Find the sources

I had to find the sources for `kali` and `libforms`, and even if you can probably find them elsewhere, for me it was convenient to find them in the [Debian packages repository](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages).

The following links are correct as today, April 12 2022:

- http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/k/kali/kali_3.1.orig.tar.gz
- http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libf/libforms/libforms_1.2.3.orig.tar.gz

but you can find them [here](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/kali) and [here](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/libforms) as well (look at the bottom of the page).

#### Compiling and linking

It doesn't go well… both packages were meant for a version of `cc` that's different from the `gcc` that you're probably using, and if you're not a C expert you're in trouble. But, Debian builds the library and Kali for Sid, so it's possible.

[Here](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/kali) and [here](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/libforms) you'll find the Debian tweaks (April 12, 2022)

- http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/k/kali/kali_3.1-19.debian.tar.xz
- http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libf/libforms/libforms_1.2.3-1.6.debian.tar.xz

so unpack the tar files from inside the top source directories, and do

```
$ while read patch_file ; do
>   patch < debian/patches/$patch_file
> done < debian/patches/series
```

The patched sources now will compile properly, and link *almost* properly.

#### Final tweak

When you finally run `./kali` the executable says the like of "I cannot find `libforms.so.2`" and stops.

You look at the the command line used to link `kali`, it looks OK, so you look at the `INSTALLATION` instructions and read

```
you should remove or rename it [libforms.so.* library] while compiling kali,
to ensure that kali is linked only with libforms.a.
Otherwise, you'll be unable to run kali, as it won't
find the shared library at run time.
```

If you do as instructed, then it works.

I say "Thank you Debian".